# Have the un-installer delete a file that was downloaded during installation with install4j

Tags: install4j

During my install4j (5.1.13) installation, a simple text file is downloaded and placed in the program's directory using the "Download File" action. This file is different from installation to installation, and therefore cannot be included in the installer itself.

What I'd like to do is to remove that file during un-installation. Is there a way of doing that using the regular "Uninstall Files" action, without explicitly using the "Delete File" action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually, I did the following:

I've downloaded the file to the system's temp directory, copied it to the installation directory, then deleted it from the temp folder. In the copy action, I chose "If created" in the Uninstall mode.

Answer (score 1):

Call

```
context.registerUninstallFile(file);
```

for that file in a "Run script" action in the installer.

Comment: Actually, I found a different way. I download the file to the system's temp directory, then copy it to the installation directory. In the copy action, I choose "If created" in the Uninstall mode.

Is this approach correct?